# Compute data from an array with VueJS

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I want to compute data from my json with vueJS

The data are like this

**json from my api**

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "votes": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "votes": 1
    },
]
```

To fetch and render this data I am using this vueJS file

**app.js**

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    results: []
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("http://example.com/votes.json")
    .then(response => {this.results = response.data})
  },
});
```

Now I want to create a vue variable to display the total of votes in my index.html

**index.html**

```
<div v-for="result in results">
    <p>Votes {{ result.votes }}.</p>
    <p>Id : {{ result.id }}</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Total of votes : {{ resultsVotes }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: And the question is...? How to compute the `resultsVotes`?

Comment: I thought "I want to compute data from my json with vueJS" & "Now I want to create a vue variable to display the total of votes in my index.html" were pretty straightforward...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `reduce` the sum of votes in the `then` function

```
axios.get("http://example.com/votes.json")
    .then(response => {
         this.results = response.data;
         this.resultsVotes = this.results.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr.votes, 0);
    });
```

Comment: This code displays the total but this error occurs `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"`

Comment: I haven't work with `id` property in my code. The problem is in another place

Comment: Need to use ``parseFloat(curr.votes)`` to prevent string type.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to compute resultVotes, `computed` value is recommended:

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    results: []
  },
  computed: {
    resultVotes () {
      return this.results.reduce((sum, val) => sum + val.votes, 0);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("http://example.com/votes.json")
    .then(response => {this.results = response.data})
  },
});
```

Comment: With this I got `this.resultsVotes = this.results.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr.votes, 0);`